# Rendering social icons from font awesome on a vue component

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, web, font-awesome

So currently I am trying to develop my own website, and I am switching from the regular HTML,CSS, and JS paradigm to using VueJs. I am struggling to transfer some of the code I have from my original HTML file to a Vue JS component, specifically my code that is rendering social icons. Most of the tutorials I am seeing, are rendering it on the main App.vue, however, when I am trying to render on a child component I am getting a bit stuck.

[Here is my original HTML code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaDxx.png)

[Here is my configuration to import my social icons:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6C2U.png)

Currently, I have followed the tutorial where after doing this import in my main.js, I simply tried replacing

```
<i class="fa fa-github fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

in my component template with

```
<fa-icon :icon="['fas', 'github']"/>,
```

however, nothing is rendering. I didn't import anything in my child component, because I thought with the initial import's I may not have to do anything. Would love to know any insights on going about this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Font Awesome 5, brand icons use the `fab` prefix.

Therefore

```
<fa-icon :icon="['fas', 'github']"/>,
```

Should be

```
<fa-icon :icon="['fab', 'github']"/>,
```

[fab fa-github](https://fontawesome.com/icons/github?style=brands)